# list of dictionary Sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

May be this is a duplicate. I didnt find same type of question
I have a list of dictionary, for example

```
mylist=[
    {'month':'MAR2011','amount':90},
    {'month':'MAR2013','amount':190},
    {'month':'JUN2011','amount':290},
    {'month':'AUG2011','amount':930},
    {'month':'DEC2011','amount':30},
    {'month':'NOV2010','amount':40},
    {'month':'FEB 2013','amount':760},
    {'month':'SEP 2012','amount':330},
    {'month':'APR2013','amount':50},
    {'month':'NOV 2011','amount':450},
    {'month':'OCT 2012','amount':450},
]
```

I want to get  output like this :

```
[
{'month':'FEB 2013','amount':760},
{'month':'MAR2011','amount':90},
{'month':'MAR2013','amount':190},
{'month':'APR 2013','amount':50},
{'month':'JUN2011','amount':290},
{'month':'AUG2011','amount':930},
{'month':'SEP 2012','amount':330},
{'month':'OCT 2012','amount':450},
{'month':'NOV2010','amount':40},
{'month':'NOV 2011','amount':450},
{'month':'DEC2011','amount':30},
]
```

Dont want to consider the year. sort according to the month.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a dictionary mapping month to an ordinal:

```
from calendar import month_abbr

month_to_index = {month.upper(): i for i, month in enumerate(month_abbr[1:])}
```

and use that to sort:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: month_to_index[d['month'][:3]])
```

Demo:

```
>>> from calendar import month_abbr
>>> month_to_index = {month.upper(): i for i, month in enumerate(month_abbr[1:])}
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: month_to_index[d['month'][:3]]))
[{'amount': 760, 'month': 'FEB 2013'},
 {'amount': 90, 'month': 'MAR2011'},
 {'amount': 190, 'month': 'MAR2013'},
 {'amount': 50, 'month': 'APR2013'},
 {'amount': 290, 'month': 'JUN2011'},
 {'amount': 930, 'month': 'AUG2011'},
 {'amount': 330, 'month': 'SEP 2012'},
 {'amount': 450, 'month': 'OCT 2012'},
 {'amount': 40, 'month': 'NOV2010'},
 {'amount': 450, 'month': 'NOV 2011'},
 {'amount': 30, 'month': 'DEC2011'}]
```

To sort on month first, year second, return a tuple from the key function:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: (month_to_index[d['month'][:3]], d['month'][-4:]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: (month_to_index[d['month'][:3]], d['month'][-4:])))
[{'amount': 760, 'month': 'FEB 2013'},
 {'amount': 90, 'month': 'MAR2011'},
 {'amount': 190, 'month': 'MAR2013'},
 {'amount': 50, 'month': 'APR2013'},
 {'amount': 290, 'month': 'JUN2011'},
 {'amount': 930, 'month': 'AUG2011'},
 {'amount': 330, 'month': 'SEP 2012'},
 {'amount': 450, 'month': 'OCT 2012'},
 {'amount': 40, 'month': 'NOV2010'},
 {'amount': 450, 'month': 'NOV 2011'},
 {'amount': 30, 'month': 'DEC2011'}]
```

In this specific case there is no difference because the per-month data is already in sorted order.

Comment: you might have to `.lower() ` ... or `.upper()`  :)

Comment: @wim: Yup, a little slow on the draw today.

Comment: or you could put `.capitalize()` into the lambda, that's probably nicer

Comment: No, because then you'd be calling that N times versus a limit to just 12 function calls for the mapping. Once. At import time. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There was a mistake in my question.i have update it now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters, how to sort it if want to consider the year also?

Comment: @AnomA: return a tuple: `lambda d: (month_to_index[d['month'][:3]], d['month'][-4:])`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping dictionary first that maps months to numbers:

```
>>> import re
>>> import pprint
>>> dic = {'JAN':1,'FEB':2,'MAR':3,'APR':4,'MAY':5,'JUN':6,'JULY':7,'AUG':8,'SEP':9,'OCT':10,'NOV':11,'DEC':12}
def func(x):
    m = re.search(r'[A-Z]+',x['month'])
    return dic[m.group(0)]
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(mylist, key = func))
[{'amount': 760, 'month': 'FEB 2013'},
 {'amount': 90, 'month': 'MAR2011'},
 {'amount': 190, 'month': 'MAR2013'},
 {'amount': 50, 'month': 'APR2013'},
 {'amount': 290, 'month': 'JUN2011'},
 {'amount': 930, 'month': 'AUG2011'},
 {'amount': 330, 'month': 'SEP 2012'},
 {'amount': 450, 'month': 'OCT 2012'},
 {'amount': 40, 'month': 'NOV2010'},
 {'amount': 450, 'month': 'NOV 2011'},
 {'amount': 30, 'month': 'DEC2011'}]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. There was a mistake in my question,I have updated